# Why isn't there support for Visual Basic syntax?

Tags: support, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Whenever I post a question or an answer that contains Visual Basic code, I usually try to add comments to my code to make it easier to read. However, Stack Overflow does not understand the syntax of VB and treats VB comments as Strings.

```
Dim text As String = "Hello, World"   'The text variable holds Hello, World
```

Not only that, it also fails to identify keywords. This makes it a bit difficult to understand, especially when the code has several lines of comments.

Comment: But there is... where you're seeing VB code not being highlighted correctly, the question probably isn't tagged correctly.

Comment: @BoltClock Look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48257615/736172 and see what I had to do so that the editor renders comments as it should

Comment: Well that's just unfortunate then. It then boils down to the same problem I have with [css].

Comment: @BoltClock The question is tagged `vb.net` and maybe the code in the question is colored properly, but in my answer, there is no way to tag my answer as `vb.net`. Maybe SO only formats the question's code as it was tagged

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is support for VB syntax highlighting:

```vb
Dim text As String = "Hello, World"   'The text variable holds Hello, World
```

Questions where the only language tag is [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) or [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) should highlight correctly. Many questions, for some strange reason, are tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)[vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) when the environment is strictly VB.NET and the asker is only interested in answers in VB.NET. Those questions should be retagged.

The example you cited seems to be an unfortunate case of questions with multiple language tags that all apply (in your case, SQL and VB). [A similar problem exists with HTML/CSS questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions) In this case, the only workaround is to force it with a language hint:

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->

    Dim text As String = "Hello, World"   'The text variable holds Hello, World
```

Comment: Excellent. That is exactly what I needed to know. I will add that to all of my upcoming answers (and questions, as well)

Comment: FTR, [tag:vbscript] also grants highlighting, exactly the same `lang-vb`.